# react sourcemap for jsx

Tags: reactjs, redux

Anyone know if this is the standard source-map for cross-builder/react now? Devtools is showing what the jsx is compiled into, not the actual jsx from the file. I've tried changing the `devtool:'source-map'` settings in the webpack config but not luck. This is straight out of the [Crossbuilder project](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/crossbuilder).

[image: source map]

Editor:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue. The sourcemap from above was done using 'eval' from webpack devtool option. Changing it to 'source-map' fixed it.